# Sending a file through Gmail from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, gmail

I am looking for a program that can:

- send a file through Gmail from Windows Explorer (e.g. right click on the file(s) and send to > Mail Recipient)

[image]

I don't want to use a mail client like Thunderbird or Outlook: I want to use the Gmail web interface.

If possible:

- free
- open the draft email in Google Chrome so that I can use the Gmail web interface features to complete my email before sending it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Affixa](http://www.affixa.com/):

- free
- send to > Mail Recipient will be were directed to the account you have configured in Affixa (e.g. Gmail but other websites are supported as well). It will first logging to your Gmail account (using the standard [Google Accounts Authentication and Authorization](https://developers.google.com/accounts/) so security is ok), then upload your files as attachments in a new draft:

[image]

[image]

- a new tab will open in Google Chrome and display the new draft.

Note that there are a bunch of potentially interesting features available in the paid version only:

[image]